# Zend Form Element Notes

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I have built a zend form element for html content (general notes).

```
class Sistema_Form_Note extends Zend_Form_Element_Xhtml {

    public $helper = 'formNote';

    public function isValid($value){
        return true;
    }

}
```

It's working fine however it goes as a field and when I go to insert the post data on my database, the index note element appears.

```
POST array('name' => 'John'
  'note1' => ...);
```

How could I remove it without using the `removeElement()` method on the controller? Is there any way to tell on the class it shouldn't be a "db field"?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out, looking how submit button is removed, It can be solved overring contruct method and passing ignore option as true.

```
class Sistema_Form_Note extends Zend_Form_Element_Xhtml {

    public $helper = 'formNote';

    public function __construct($spec, $options = null)
    {
       if (is_string($spec) && ((null !== $options) && is_string($options))) {
            $options = array('label' => $options);
       }

       if (!isset($options['ignore'])) {
            $options['ignore'] = true;
       }

       parent::__construct($spec, $options);
    }

    public function isValid($value){
       return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've created a similar element with the same requirements. I know you've already answered this but mine contains a solution that prevents the value from being overridden by post data (if you use the `$_value` property).

```
class My_Form_Element_Note extends Zend_Form_Element_Xhtml
{
    public $helper = 'formNote';

    protected $_ignore = true;

    public function setValue($value)
    {
        if (null === $this->_value) {
            parent::setValue($value);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me just it has helped:

class App_Form_Element_Note extends Zend_Form_Element_Xhtml
{

```
public $helper = 'formHtml';

public function __construct($spec, $options = null) {

     parent::__construct($spec, $options);
     $this->setIgnore(true);
}

public function isValid($value){
      return true;
}
```

}

The overwride of 'IsValid' function made the note appears when the validator acts.